# CSS Conditional h2 text

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a conditional for the h2 text of a class? the h2 does not have a unique class or id to it, and multiple h2's with a dynamic changing order. So i can't target say the 3rd h2 because its always shifting.

```
h2.arker.fun.header {
// some statement If h2 text = "Gamer" then set text-transform: lowercase
}
```

Comment: No. CSS can't detect content...only style it.

Answer (score 2):

There was once proposed one pseudo class known as **:contains** to handle this situation. But they haven't added it yet in the current draft of CSS3.

However you may use some Javascript. For Example to deal with this problem

```
for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;){
    if (/\bSpecificWord\b/i.test(document.links[i].innerHTML)
        document.links[i].style.color= 'red'; }
```

Hope you are not restrained from using Javascript.

Comment: This is the way to go. If they are using the JQuery, libs, there are much better ways to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others (@Paulie_D, @Mia Marks, @YourFriend) have already pointed out, there is no CSS < 4 selector based on content and the closest you can get is the attribute selector.

**Just a crazy idea:**

```css
h2.arker.fun.header:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

h2.arker.fun.header[data-text="Gamer"] {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="arker fun header" data-text="Gamer"></h2>
```

**don't do it at home...**

Comment: That would **add** the text...not detect it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sure, add it and apply the style based on the attribute's content... it's a crappy idea but hey, it's just for fun.

Comment: So a fundamental change to the HTML to remove **actual content** from the DOM...ugh!

Comment: @Paulie_D Of course this is ugly as hell, again, DON'T TRY THIS.

Comment: @coma Your fun may ruin someone's life xD

Comment: @YourFriend I'm about to delete this since I suffer from downvote panic.

Comment: @coma LOL, I don't think this question will remain on the top for much time. Soon it will get hidden beneath other questions

Answer (score -2):

u can add attribute in that h2 tag 
and put the condition like:
h2[if='mytype']{text-transform:lowercase;}

Comment: This is not correct. CSS can't detect inner text. You would have to use JQuery or something similar.